# Trello: Is there a way to remove suggested labels?

Tags: trello-labels

If a label is no longer being used on any cards, is there a way to remove it from the list of available labels?

For example, our board contains two red labels, "URGENT" and "Urgent". I have cleaned up our board to remove all instances of "Urgent" and would like to prevent it's appearance again in the list of labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on any card
2. Click labels to view existing labels
3. Next to each label is a pencil icon you can use to edit the name and colour of the label. Click it.
4. Click the delete button. This removes all instances of the label so be sure to filter for that label first.

[image: How to delete a label]